# Roasting two ham roasts at once

Tags: roasting, fresh, ham

I am cooking two fresh ham roasts at once for a large crowd.  The instructions are for minutes per pound.  Do I add my roasts for total pounds or figure for one?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your oven and how big the hams are. If you try to cram 2 big hams into your oven and it's not a fan oven then you probably need to add extra time. If they are moderate size then it shouldn't make much difference at all. If they are big but you have a fan oven then you shouldn't need to add time.

The best way to make sure something is done is not by time, but using a meat thermometer. When the ham is 150F at the center of the meat's mass then it is ready to come out, below that it still needs more cooking.

Answer (score 3):

No, cooking two roasts at once will not change the cooking time for either.

Remove each when it is cooked through.  Since these are fresh ham roasts, you should be cooking them until they are done to the standard are using, not based on a single time.

If you are using a low and slow method, there is enough flexibility that you can probably leave them in together until they are both done, assuming they are even close in size.